# How to get the marginal effects after lm_robust() with clustered standard errors?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, lm, standard-error

I am running a regression with clustered standard errors by year. This is easy to do with Stata but I have to do it with R, so I run it using the `lm_robust()` function from the `estimatr` package. The problem is that I must now get the marginal effects of some variables but I cannot do it and I guess it is because of the cluster standard error. I followed what is on the manual for `lm_robust()` and I've seen they only used the margins command from the margins package for other functions without clustered standard errors... Does anyone have a clue on how can I get and plot the marginal effects?

```
set.seed(42)
library(fabricatr)
library(randomizr)
dat <- fabricate(
  N = 100,                        # sample size
  x = runif(N, 0, 1),             # pre-treatment covariate
  y0 = rnorm(N, mean = x),        # control potential outcome
  y1 = y0 + 0.35,                 # treatment potential outcome
  z = complete_ra(N),             # complete random assignment to treatment
  y = ifelse(z, y1, y0),          # observed outcome

  # We will also consider clustered data
  clust = sample(rep(letters[1:20], each = 5)),
  z_clust = cluster_ra(clust),
  y_clust = ifelse(z_clust, y1, y0)
)
```

Then when I run the regression with the `lm_robust()` function:

```
library(estimatr)
lmout_cl <- lm_robust(
  y_clust ~ z_clust + x,
  data = dat,
  clusters = clust
)
```

And finally, I try to get the margins...

```
library(margins)
mar_cl <- margins(lmout_cl)
```

But this results in an error:

```
Error in attributes(.Data) <- c(attributes(.Data), attrib) :'names' attribute 
[1] must be the same length as the vector [0]
```

Comment: This is a bug! (lm_robust objects are supposed to work with margins and usually do!) we'll be addressing soon, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `estimatr::lm_robust()` yields a `"lm_robust"` object which seems not to be supported by `margins()` at the moment. We can use `miceadds::lm.cluster()` instead—and obtain the same clustered standard errors as Stata at that.

```
library(miceadds)

lmout_cl <- lm.cluster(y_clust ~ z_clust + x, data=dat, cluster=dat$clust)
```

This results in a list with two elements, where the normal `lm`-object is stored in the first element and the variance-covariance matrix with clustered standard errors the second (see `str(lmout_cl)`):

```
> names(lmout_cl)
[1] "lm_res" "vcov"
```

`margins()` now can be specified as `margins(model=model, vcov=vcov)`, so we say:

```
mar_cl <- with(lmout_cl, margins(lm_res, vcov=vcov))
```

***Yielding***

```
> mar_cl
Average marginal effects
stats::lm(formula = formula, data = data)

 z_clust     x
  0.6558 1.444
```

and

```
> summary(mar_cl)
  factor    AME     SE      z      p  lower  upper
       x 1.4445 0.3547 4.0728 0.0000 0.7494 2.1396
 z_clust 0.6558 0.1950 3.3633 0.0008 0.2736 1.0379
```

with clustered standard errors.

---

***Comparison with Stata***

**R**

```
foreign::write.dta(dat, "dat.dta")  # export as Stata data to wd
```

**Stata**

```
. use dat, clear
(Written by R.              )

. quietly regress y_clust z_clust x, vce(cluster clust)

. mfx

Marginal effects after regress
      y  = Fitted values (predict)
         =  .67420391
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
variable |      dy/dx    Std. Err.     z    P>|z|  [    95% C.I.   ]      X
---------+--------------------------------------------------------------------
 z_clust*|   .6557558      .19498    3.36   0.001   .273609   1.0379        .5
       x |   1.444481      .35466    4.07   0.000   .749352  2.13961   .524479
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
(*) dy/dx is for discrete change of dummy variable from 0 to 1

.
```

As we can clearly see—in doing so R yields the same as Stata concerning both, clustered standard errors and marginal effects.

Comment: `lm_robust` can provide different SE estimates (each of which makes different assumptions, so not clear which is "correct"). But it can reproduce stata! `lm_robust(y_clust ~ z_clust + x, data = dat, clusters = clust, se_type = "stata")`

Comment: @AlexCoppock Thanks for pointing this out. You're right, I've edited the wording of my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

Apologies for this bug which prevents `margins()` from working with `lm_robust()` objects with non-numeric clusters in `estimatr` versions 0.10 and earlier. This was created by the internal way both `estimatr::lm_robust()` and `margins::margins()` handle which variables are in the model.

The bug has since been solved and so you have two solutions within `estimatr`.

Let me first generate the data.

```
library(fabricatr)
library(randomizr)
dat <- fabricate(
  N = 100,
  x = runif(N),
  clust = sample(rep(letters[1:20], each = 5)),
  y_clust = rnorm(N),
  z_clust = cluster_ra(clust),
)
```

---

**Get the latest version of `estimatr` (v0.11.0)**

The dev version on https://declaredesign.org/r/estimatr has a fix for this bug, and it will be on CRAN in the next month or so.

```
install.packages("estimatr", dependencies = TRUE,
                 repos = c("http://r.declaredesign.org", "https://cloud.r-project.org"))
library(estimatr)
lmout_cl <- lm_robust(
  y_clust ~ z_clust + x,
  data = dat,
  clusters = clust
)
library(margins)
mar_cl <- margins(lmout_cl)
```

---

**Use numeric clusters with CRAN version of `estimatr` (v0.10.0)**

A workaround with the existing version of `estimatr` on CRAN is to use numeric clusters instead of character clusters

```
dat <- fabricate(
  N = 100,
  x = runif(N),
  clust = sample(rep(1:20, each = 5)),
  y_clust = rnorm(N),
  z_clust = cluster_ra(clust),
)
install.packages("estimatr")
library(estimatr)
lmout_cl <- lm_robust(
  y_clust ~ z_clust + x,
  data = dat,
  clusters = clust
)
mar_cl <- margins(lmout_cl)
```